# Simple image operations for .NET Core 6 and beyond

Tags: .net-core, system.drawing, system.drawing.common

I have some C# code that relies on doing really basic graphic operations such as getting and setting pixels, and drawing texts over images. This uses the System.Drawing package which Microsoft has dropped the ball on.

Microsoft says this: Migrate to one of the following libraries: ImageSharp, SkiaSharp, Microsoft.Maui.Graphics. The latter appears to be ill-documented and unstable.

Could anyone with experience with these packages suggest an easy and simple way forward?

I am even wondering if it might pay to write my own library for the Windows bitmap format (which is sufficient for my purposes).

Yours frustratingly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which platform you are building your app, but SkiaSharp 2.80.2 or 2.80.3 can be a good choice. There are quite a bit problems in newer packages, so you need to be careful which version you install so that you do not run into performance problems or bugs.